# How do I obtain reference to my SCM object in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am unable to obtain a reference to my SCM object in my Jenkins Pipeline. In my current case, it is necessary to retrieve this reference to be used in the JIRA plugin, as [shown here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#jiraissueupdater-usage-example).

I created a simple test case

```
node("master"){
    def gitScm  = git url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-plugin.git', branch: 'master'
    echo "my git scm is "+gitScm 
    step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.JiraIssueUpdater',
        issueSelector: [$class: 'hudson.plugins.jira.selector.DefaultIssueSelector'],
        scm: gitScm])
    gitScm = null
}
```

and I always get a `null` `gitScm` object, and then a failure in my JIRA update:

> my git scm is null

even though git repo checks out successfully.

Answer (score 3):

If this question is still relevant, I can think of two options:

1. If you're in a multibranch pipeline environment, you can simply use the 'scm' variable, which is injected into the build by Jenkins
2. If not you can get a reference (to Git) using:

   ```
   def scm = [
       $class: 'GitSCM', 
       userRemoteConfigs: [[url: , refSpec: ]],
       branches: [[name: ]]
   ]
   ```

Substitute variables and type of SCM as needed. This allows for subsequent statements like `checkout scm`

Comment: case 2 worked for a remote repository in a multibranch pipeline.